# Using Java Stack with String elements

Tags: java, stack, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use a java Stack to push String values:names into it, derived from input from a Scanner method.  I'd then want to pop the names from the stack, and after show the logical and physical elements of the stack.  I believe I should be using an Array Stack but not entirely sure as I don't have much quidance or experience with Stacks.

Currently I am getting the following error when compiling the Stack.java file.

```
Stack.java:24: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method push(java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.String[]
stack.push(s);
```

I've been researching this and trying different code for days, but as I am very new to this, and I have run out of ways to manipulate the code to make it work.

I would highly appreciate some advice...tnx!

Here is my Stack Class code:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Stack {  //Create Class

        private String stack[] ;
        private int top;
        private static final int SIZE = 5;
        String name;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        public Stack(int SIZE){
            stack = new String [SIZE];
            top = 0;
        }

    public void push(String s) {    //Method to Insert

        if (isStackFull())
            System.out.println ("Stack is Full ");  //If Stack full Print Full
        else {
            while (scan.hasNextLine()){
                s = scan.nextLine();
                stack.push(s);
            }
                stack[top] = s;
                top++;      
        } 
    }

    public String pop() {   //Method to Delete

        if (isStackEmpty())
            System.out.println ("Stack is Empty "); //If Stack empty print Empty
        else{
            String value = stack[top];
            top--;
            return value;
        }
        return stack[top];
    }   

    public String toString( ){      //Method print Logical Stack
            if (isStackEmpty( ))
                System.out.println ("Stack is Empty "); //If Stack empty print Empty
            else 
                System.out.println("\nThe Stack");
                String result = "";

                for (int j=0; j < top; j++)

                    result = result + stack[j].toString() + "\n";

                return result;
    }

    public boolean isStackEmpty() { //Method boolean type to check empty Stack
        return (top == 0);
    }

    public boolean isStackFull() {      //Method boolean type to check full Stack
        return (top == (SIZE-1));
    }
}
```

For the StackTest Code, generally I call the methods in Stack.  Eg.

```
public class StackTest { //Create class
    public static void main(String[] args){     //Main Method
        Stack n = new Stack();  //Declare variables
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
        String response;                        
        char x;
```

and

```
while(x != 'q' && x != 'Q'){        //While loop initiates if no q or Q char input

                switch(x){                      //Start of swtich for insert, delete, print physical, logical or default quite  
                    case 'i':                   
                        n.push();                       
                        System.out.println ("Inserted item from Stack");
                        break;
                    case 'd':
                        n.pop();
                        System.out.println ("Deleted item from Stack");
                        break;
                    case 'p':
                        n.toString();
                        System.out.println ("Printed Physical Stack ");
                        break;
```

Comment: `stack` is a String array, which has no `push` method.

Comment: If you need a `Stack` implementation that doesn't require thread-safety, [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) is preferrable.

Answer (score 1):

Your `push(String s)` is method is calling `push()` on `String` which is incorrect, moreover the logic for `push(String s)` is complicated, rather it is simple as shown below in the code with comments:

```
public void push(String s) {
    if (isStackFull())
        System.out.println ("Stack is Full "); //If Stack full Print Full
    else {
        stack[top] = s; //just add the string to the top of the stack
        top++; //increment top
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the push method itself you are trying to call stack.push hence it is throwing error. replace the stack.push to stack[top_index]= the string.

Comment: Tnx all!   I'll try your recommendations.

Comment: Ok...tnx.  In the push method I deleted the stack.push(s) call and this resolved the compile error.  Now I have a compile error in StackTest which I don't understand.  It gets hung up in my switch statement: n.push()

Comment: Tnx.  In push method I deleted the stack.push(s) call and this fixed the compile error.  Now I have a compile error in StackTest.  Its at my switch statement: n.push() and I assume all of the n.X statements.  Above, with Stack n = new Stack() and then n.push() I am trying to declare a new stack n which takes an input name from a scanner method and pushes it to the stack.  Not sure why it can't find the constructor Stack(). In Stack.java did I get the Stack constructor right?  I wanted to construct a stack of strings that is limited to SIZE which = 5 elements.

Comment: The error is: StackTest.java:6: cannot find symbol symbol  : constructor Stack();  location: class Stack; Stack n = new Stack(); StackTest.java:32: push(java.lang.String) in Stack cannot be applied to (); n.push();

Comment: Never Mind.  I resolved the issue and corrected my stack constructor.  Thanks All!